# Parsing text in a single column

Tags: r, data-manipulation, stringr

I'm trying to take the term in the variable column, and parse the "psi#." off leaving the rest.  This variables will change over time.

[image]

I tried:

```
df <- psi2 <-  as.data.frame(piecewise_seg2$psi) %>%
 rownames_to_column( var = "variable") %>%
 separate(variable, c("psi*"))
```

However, that just leaves "psi."  I don't know regex but I did try

```
str_split_fixed(psi2$variable, "psi*", "[abc]+$", 2)
```

That didn't work either.

I did try to find something like this but mostly found parsing one character vector into a list.  Any help?

Comment: what is the expected results?

Comment: Can't you just separate on the period?

Comment: I think you want to *remove* it, not *parse* it. (Parse has a very specific meaning in programming.) How about `str_replace(yourdata$variable, pattern = "psi..", replacement = "")`. In regex, `.` matches any single character, so that will match `psi` and the next two characters (which look to be a number and a dot, in your example).

Comment: All you need is `gsub('psi\\d+\\.', '', psi2$variable)` imo

Comment: When asking a question, it is always good to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). That makes it a lot easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just remove the `psi1.` with different numbers you can use [`str_replace`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.1.0/topics/str_replace):

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("psi2.1", "psi1.2", "psi33.55", "psi12.42"))
df %>% mutate(var = str_replace(var, "psi(\\d+)\\.", ""))
#   var
# 1   1
# 2   2
# 3  55
# 4  42
```

Solution by @Jaap:

```
gsub('psi\\d+\\.', '', psi2$variable)
```

And benchmark, I have added `stringi::stri_replace_first_regex` and `perl = TRUE` to `gsub`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  str_replace = str_replace(df$var, "psi\\d+\\.", ""),
  stri_replace_all = stringi::stri_replace_first_regex(df$var, "psi\\d+\\.", ""),
  sub = sub(".*\\.", "", df$var),
  gsub = gsub('psi\\d+\\.', '', df$var),
  gsub_perl = gsub('psi\\d+\\.', '', df$var, perl = TRUE),
  times = 10000
)

Unit: microseconds
             expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq       max neval
      str_replace 96.661 106.101 129.08727 110.632 117.805  3951.009 10000
 stri_replace_all 28.319  33.228  41.57426  36.626  39.647  1980.413 10000
              sub 14.349  17.369  22.21423  19.257  23.033  1682.124 10000
             gsub 18.879  22.278  34.89121  24.921  28.697 63495.163 10000
        gsub_perl 76.272  79.293  88.32751  81.558  84.956  1865.251 10000
```

The `sub` solution is the fastest.

Applying the benchmark on a larger dataset:

```
df <- df[sample(nrow(df), 1e6, replace = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  str_replace = str_replace(df$var, "psi\\d+\\.", ""),
  stri_replace_all = stringi::stri_replace_first_regex(df$var, "psi\\d+\\.", ""),
  sub = sub(".*\\.", "", df$var),
  gsub = gsub('psi\\d+\\.', '', df$var),
  gsub_perl = gsub('psi\\d+\\.', '', df$var, perl = TRUE),
  times = 50
)
```

the result:

```
Unit: milliseconds
             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
      str_replace 293.2773 301.9520 311.9032 308.5192 322.4974 344.7649    50  b  
 stri_replace_all 294.8729 298.8479 316.9213 306.4369 317.3555 518.5287    50  b  
              sub 468.2134 473.1803 487.0336 485.1354 498.1503 527.2476    50   c 
             gsub 649.6209 673.4312 690.7942 683.6022 701.3134 909.2599    50    d
        gsub_perl 251.0663 255.1404 263.9778 260.3426 274.6684 287.3492    50 a
```

Comment: `sub` will be fast than `gsub` since it is not greedy. That for sure I know. But it is uncertain why `sub` will be faster than `str_replace` yet the essence of the package are to make base functions faster

Comment: @Onyambu The essence of stringr is _not_ to base functions faster. It's to provide a consistent interface

Comment: @Hadley yes for sure, though I believe you did optimize it in terms of speed thus to my opinion. It should be faster than the base R. When a function takes ages to run in base R we usually tend to run to the various packages for alternatives

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove the `psi.` you can use `sub` function in base R

```
j=c("psi1.rba_bucket","psi2.rba_bucket","psi1.credit_tier_bucket")
sub(".*\\.","",j)
[1] "rba_bucket"         "rba_bucket"        
[3] "credit_tier_bucket"

sub("psi..","",j)
[1] "rba_bucket"         "rba_bucket"        
[3] "credit_tier_bucket"
```

Comment: Hello @Onyambu.  What if I wanted to parse psi, the number, and the rest into separate columns?

     psi    #       variable
     psi    1      rba_bucket
     psi    2      rba_bucket

Comment: do `strcapture("([a-z]+)(\\d+).(.*)",j,data.frame(A=character(),B=numeric(),C=character()))`